# Can there be different particular solutions for a differential equation since the constant MAY change?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Say, we had the following differential equation:

$dy/dx = 2(y^2)$

Now, when we solve it, we may get one of the following equations, depending on IF we decide to multiply something with the constant OR leave it as it is:

$y = 1/-2x-2c$ (if we decide to multiply -2 with the constant)

$y = 1/-2x+c$ (if we decide to leave the constant alone)

If we're asked to find the particular solution for when x=2 and y=1, obviously, the value of the constant and the particular solution in each case will be different. Now, I'm a bit confused here. Some of the teachers like to leave the constant alone, explaining that it has a particular value which can not change and hence, we leave it as it is. Other teachers like to multiply stuff with the constant as well.

What's the right way to approach this, and why?

EDIT: The value of C maybe different, but the constant we get at the end, after solving for the particular solution and plugging the value of the constant into the general solution, will exactly be the same! Thanks, Joe!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= 2y^2 \\
\int 1 \, dx &= \int \frac{1}{2}y^{-2} \, dy \\
x + C &= -\frac{1}{2}y^{-1} \\
y(x+C) &= -\frac{1}{2} \\
y &= -\frac{1}{2(x+C)}
\end{align}
What the solution to this differential equation shows is that any function $y$ of the form
$$
y(x)=-\frac{1}{2(x+\text{some arbitrary constant})}
$$
has the derivative $2y^2$. It doesn't matter how you label that constant. For example, you could use $C$, you could use $K$, you could even use $17C-398$; it's all the same. It is very common to not even bother multiplying the constant as you are solving the equation, because we just need *some* letter that represents a member of the real numbers. For example, you might see
\begin{align}
2y &= 5x + C \\
y &= 5x + C
\end{align}
More formally, this could be justified in the following way:
\begin{align}
2y &= 5x + C \\
y &= \frac{5}{2}x + C/2
\end{align}
Let $K=C/2$. Then we have $y=\frac{5}{2}x+K$. However, since the value of $K$ is arbitrary, we may relabel it as $C$. (This is despite the fact that we are using the letter $C$ to represent something that earlier we would denote $C/2$.) Again, we just need to use a letter to emphasise that it is a family of solutions to the differential equation that we have found. The constant $C$ is just an arbitrary member of the real numbers.

Comment: So, we can say that there are a bunch of particular solutions to a differential equation?

Comment: @ihateelectricalphysics Yes, absolutely. Heck, we don't even need to be solving a differential equation. When we write $$\int x^2 \, dx = \frac{x^3}{3}+C \, ,$$what we mean is that the derivative of any function $f$ of the form $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$ is $x^2$. So $\frac{x^3}{3}+5$ is a solution, $\frac{x^3}{3}+28.3$ is a solution, and so on. This is a *family* of solutions—no function has a unique antiderivative.

Comment: Ah, I understand! Thank you for lending me your time :D!

Comment: @ihateelectricalphysics That's great to hear. Feel free to upvote this answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hold on, I don't get one thing. How can an equation have several PARTICULAR solutions? When we have particular conditions set in, then shouldn't the constant too be particular for those particular conditions?

Comment: @ihateelectricalphysics If you simply write $dy/dx = 2y^2$, with no further information given, then there isn't a unique solution. This is in the same way that $x^2 + 3x + 2 = 0$ doesn't have a unique solution. If, however, you give more information, such as $x=0$ when $y=0$, then there is a single solution. If the constant didn't disappear, then there wouldn't be a single solution. In the above example, we could use the fact that $x=0$ when $y=0$ to deduce that $C=0$.

Comment: Ah, yes! So, my question essentially was that, if the constant we get (in the general solution), looks something like $5/2C$ or $3C$, when finding its value for the particular solution, do we consider the constants as well? Some teachers like to consider the other constants like $5/2$ and $3$, some don't. What should we do and why?

Comment: @ihateelectricalphysics It doesn't actually matter, because either way we would conclude that $C=0$ or $5/2 C = 0$ or something like that. It's helpful to remember that these symbols are just standing in for numbers. Basically, if we found that the solution to a differential equation is $f(x) + \text{ some arbitrary constant}$, then we can use the extra information to conclude that that arbitrary constant is equal to $0$ or $5$ or whatever.

Comment: Here's the thing, though! IF we get an expression like $5/2Cx$, wouldn't the constant now matter? If we didn't consider $5/2%, the solution would look very different under a set of conditions.

Comment: @ihateelectricalphysics The value of $C$ might be different, but the actual constant that you tack on at the end of your solution would be the same.

Comment: Ah, crap! I should've at least tried to work that out on paper first before asking you! You're right! Thanks a bunch!